# Adding subclass methods to parents game loop

Tags: ruby, inheritance

A little summary of the code I am working on is several command line games which inherit from a game class that supplies methods and attributes most command line games use, i.e. the board, configuration menu, check_for_winner, game loop, etc. Instead of prompting the user to enter a space using gets, I created the board and menus to interact with the arrow keys and display a highlight over the currently selected option. Instead of re-writing all these loops to gather arrow key input without requiring the return key to be pressed, I decided to have a parent game class which will run methods of their subclass in the game loop. Below is the game_loop code I am working with

```
def game_loop
    display_main_menu if defined? display_main_menu
    begin
        space = @board.interact {|char| @quit = true if char == 'q'}
        move(space) if defined? move
    end until @quit || @winner != nil || (end_game if defined? end_game)
    print %x{clear}
    game_summary if defined? game_summary
    puts "Play Again? y/n".center(80)
    restart if defined? restart
    game_loop if get_char == 'y'
end
```

My question is, is there a better way for me to write the game loop method instead of calling methods which I expect the child class to have. I want the game loop to have the basic structure of the game, so in pseudo-code it would be

1. Display the main menu, which adjust rules of the game
2. Once the user selects the "Play game" option, get the players move
3. Repeat step 2 until a winner is found or there are no more moves
4. Display a summary of the game, i.e. each players win, loss, and draw count
5. Ask to play again, if not return to game selection

It works the way I have it written, but I feel there has to be a better way to structure the game loop without checking if the methods are defined. Also, is inheritance a good way to go about implementing the game loop or is there a better way like mapping keys in a hash to methods of the child class.

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can define those instance methods like `display_main_menu` and `move` in superclass, with empty implementation, by doing so, all the subclasses are guarenteed to have those methods, but by default do nothing, thus you don't need to check the existence of those methods. Subclasses can override those methods to provide their own features.